# ffmpeg on linux server

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have download static build for linux and save into the media temple project directory it gives me blank page. But on the windows localhost every thing working fine

```
$main_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$output= shell_exec($main_dir."/ffmpeg 2>&1");
$ourFileName = $main_dir."/testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle,$output);
fclose($ourFileHandle);
print $output;
```

Comment: Do you have access to your remote shell (Shared Hosting)?

Comment: just i have access of plusk pannel

Comment: 1. you need to make sure you can actually _execute_ that application. If it is only a hosting system then that most likely is not possible. 2. you do no error checking / handling _at all_. You are flying in the dark and wonder why something does not work... 3. did you take a loko at the http servers error log file? What does it say?

Comment: output in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/videoanalysistool/index.php on line 17

Comment: this is the log file error